# Initializing a matrix with alternating 0s and 1s in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to create an n-by-m matrix of 0s and 1s with a very simple structure:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...],
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...],
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...],
[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...],
[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...],
[0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...],
...
[... 0 0 0 1 1 1 1],
[... 0 0 0 0 1 1 1],
[... 0 0 0 0 0 1 1],
[... 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

However, I don't want to start writing loops as this is probably achievable using something built in: `A = tf.constant(???,shape(n,m))`

Note that after the first 3 rows there is simply a repetition of four 1s, followed by m-3 0s, until the last 3 rows.

So I am thinking something along the lines of a repeat of repeat, but I have no idea what syntax to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`tf.matrix_band_part()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_band_part). As per the manual, it's function is to

> Copy a tensor setting everything outside a central band in each innermost matrix to zero.

So in your case you'd create a matrix with ones, and then take a 4-wide band like this:

```
tf.matrix_band_part( tf.ones( shape = ( 1, n, m ) ), 3, 0 )
```

Tested code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones( shape = ( 1, 9, 6 ) )
y = tf.matrix_band_part( x, 3, 0 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( y )
    print ( res )
```

Output:

> [[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>    [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>    [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
>    [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
>    [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
>    [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>    [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
>    [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
>    [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]]

Comment: Thanks! Even simpler than I thought.

Comment: Sure! I know the feeling when one finds out about a new function that does _exactly_ what one needs! :D

Comment: Didn't notice till it was giving me errors, need to finish with `y=y[0]` to make it an actual matrix, or remove the 1 in the shape parameter. Is there a reason you added it?

Comment: I was under the impression `tf.matrix_band_part()` requires a batch dimension too, that's why I prepended a dim. Maybe it doesn't.